# ORACLE SQL equivalent to given mysql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I am stuck on conerting this query from mysql to oracle as oracle create problems in subquery order by. Query is:

```
SELECT bt_charges.bt_setup_id, bt_setups.name, IFNULL(bt_charges.charges_for,'OPD') as charges_for_vals, bt_charges.nc_applicable,bt_charges.unit_value,bt_charges.taxtype_id, bt_charges.id, bt_charges.amount, bt_charges.effective_date 
FROM bt_setups JOIN bt_charges ON ( bt_charges.bt_setup_id = bt_setups.id AND 
bt_charges.id = (SELECT id 
                 FROM bt_charges ilaba 
                 WHERE IFNULL(ilaba.charges_for,'OPD') = IFNULL(bt_charges.charges_for,'OPD') 
                     AND ilaba.bt_setup_id= bt_setups.id AND ilaba.effective_date <= '2014-11-10' 
                     AND ilaba.insprovider_id IS NULL AND ilaba.deleted=0 
                 ORDER BY ilaba.effective_date DESC, ilaba.date_entered DESC 
                 LIMIT 1)) 
WHERE bt_setups.status='Active' AND bt_setups.deleted=0 
    AND bt_charges.insprovider_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY bt_setups.name, charges_for ASC
```

Here, `bt_setups ( name, description )` is service provided and
 `bt_charges (effective_date date, date_entered datetime, charger_for char, bt_setup_id foreign key(bt_setups), insprovider_id foreign key(insproviders) )` contains charges for service applicable from effective_date, insprovider wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT bc.bt_setup_id, bs.name, 
       NVL(bc.charges_for,'OPD') as charges_for_vals, 
       bc.nc_applicable, bc.unit_value, bc.taxtype_id, 
       bc.id, bc.amount, bc.effective_date 
FROM bt_setups bs JOIN bt_charges bc ON ( bc.bt_setup_id = bs.id AND 
bc.id = (SELECT id FROM 
                    (SELECT ilaba.id, ilaba.bt_setup_id 
                     FROM bt_charges ilaba 
                     WHERE NVL(ilaba.charges_for,'OPD') = NVL(bc.charges_for,'OPD') 
                         AND ilaba.effective_date <= TO_DATE('2014-11-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                         AND ilaba.insprovider_id IS NULL AND ilaba.deleted=0 
                     ORDER BY ilaba.effective_date DESC, ilaba.date_entered DESC)
                 WHERE bt_setup_id = bs.id AND ROWNUM = 1
                 )) 
WHERE bs.status='Active' AND bs.deleted=0 
    AND bc.insprovider_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY bs.name, charges_for ASC;
```

`IFNULL` -> `NVL`

'2014-11-10' -> TO_DATE('2014-11-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - I suppose `ilaba.effective_date` has DATE type

LIMIT 1 -> `order by` in the subquery + `rownum=1` in the parent query

Comment: getting error: "BT_SETUPS"."ID": invalid identifier in subquery. I think outer tables are not accessible here

Comment: @wisdom I've added "bs" alias to the query

Comment: @wisdom I suppose alias won't help. I've updated the query - Oracle won't let use parent columns in subsubquery

Comment: thanks it's working one more question is there any advantage of using exists in place of `id = ` and SQL should also be valid for mysql if we replcae NVL and date func

Comment: @wisdom Sorry, EXISTS changed the query. I've updated my answer again. You needed to get id from ilaba with the latest effective_date and date_entered and check if it equals to bt_changes.id, but EXISTS checks if there is any id in ilaba